# Why won't my lights light up, even though there's power to the lights?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have new construction, one switch with power to it. From the switch I ran the wire to the first light(4 total) from the first light I ran wire to two different lights and then from one light of the second lights to the final light. I have power at all light fixture but they will not light up. Is my problem that I connected two lights to the first light where the power from the switch comes. All the lights are connected with black to black, white to white and ground to ground. The switch was wired: black from power to switch and black from wire from switch to first ligh connected to switch, both whites are connected but not to switch, grounds are to switch. Is my problem that I did not run the lights one to the next and then the next? Maybe I shouldn't have ran wire from the first light to two lights??? Please help I would have thought this would be simple as I've done 2 way switches with four lights, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bad switch; it's all good now. It was the last thing I checked.